# ios drawing lines to an imageView and combine the lines and the image to a new image, size of the image changed

Tags: ios

I have an imageView and say its size is the screen size. It displays an image which has a larger size, and the imageView's content mode is set to scaleAspectFill. Then I drawing some lines on the imageView by using UIBeizerPath.
Later I would like to generate an new image which includes the lines I drew by using drawViewHierarchyInRect. The problem is the new image size is the imageView's size, since the drawViewHierarchyInRect method works only like taking a snapshot. How Can I combine the original image with the lines I drew and at the same time, keep the image's size?

Comment: Are you working in Swift or Objective-C? (I strongly suggest using Swift. Specifically Swift 3.1.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the method `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to create an off-screen context of the desired size. (In your case, the size of the image.)

Then draw your image into the context, draw the lines on top, and extract your composite image from the context. Finally, dispose of the context.

There is tons of sample code online showing how to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. It's quite easy.